# adb cannot start daemon, CreateProcess failure, error 2

Tags: android, adb

I an unable to run `adb root` or any adb command.  I get the following error.  I set `ADB_TRACE=1`:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>adb root
system/core/adb/adb.c::main():Handling commandline()
system/core/adb/adb_client.c::_adb_connect():_adb_connect: host:version
system/core/adb/sysdeps_win32.c::socket_loopback_client():socket_loopback_client: could not connect
to tcp:5037
system/core/adb/adb_client.c::adb_connect():adb_connect: service root:
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
CreateProcess failure, error 2
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

I am using Windows 7.

From `netstat -a` I don't see anything else using port 5037.  When I run adb, I observe that adb momentarily is displayed on Task Manager, but then it goes away.  Windows Firewall is turned off.  I get the same results if I run `cmd` as administrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem long ago, but did not update this question.

I was having this issue because I was running the incorrect adb executable.  I had one executable in `C:\Windows\system32` and another in a different directory.  The version in `C:\Windows\system32` had did not have all the files needed by adb whereas the version in the other directory did.  I'm not sure what those files were, but the adb executable was the same version in both directories.  Since `C:Windows\system32` was in the PATH first, that version was executed first.  I removed adb from the Windows directory, and the problem went away.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure that all your development tools use the same version of `adb`.

One easy way to do that is to open the `Command Prompt` window as Administrator and run these 2 commands to delete all copies:

```
taskkill /f /im adb.exe
for %a in ("%systemroot%" "%userprofile%" "%path:;=";"%") do @del /q /f /s "%~a\adb.exe" "%~a\adbwinapi.dll" "%~a\adbwinusbapi.dll" 2>nul
```

Then reinstall the latest version of the `platform-tools` package from the SDK Manager or manually by downloading and unzipping the package file (check [`adb` info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/adb/info) for the link) into the `%ANDROID_SDK_HOME%` folder.

Also make sure that `%ANDROID_SDK_HOME%\platform-tools` folder is included in your `%PATH%`.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this issue by going to Task Manager and killing all the adb' then it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, to solve it, I have uninstalled the package Platform-tools on the SDK manager -> SDK tools and re-installed it.
Now, It's working correctly.

Answer (score -2):

I solved this by going to the actual platform-tools directory.

Default path is C:\Users[youruser]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools

Apparently it won't start unless you change to that directory.

Answer (score -3):

You can try this solution: Move the **adb.exe** and **adbwinapi.dll** to `X:\Windows\system`

It worked for me

Comment: Moving something to system folder is bad case.

Answer (score -4):

I got the same problem, BTW I am using win7 64bit.

solved it like this:
Move the adb.exe and adbwinapi.dll to X:\Windows\SysWOW64

hope useful