# Cannot run adb command in ubuntu adb server is out of date

Tags: android, shell, ubuntu

when i run `adb devices`

```
    adb server is out of date.  killing...
    cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
    ADB server didn't ACK
    * failed to start daemon *
    error:
```

its the same as this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757191/adb-and-genymotion-error-adb-server-is-out-of-date-killing-cannot-bind-tc)
. some of the comments say that try to **`adb kill-server`** then start adb again but it does not work in my **ubuntu** machine.

I have also tried **`killall -9 adb`** which is the correct answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431972/android-studio-lollipop-adb-genymotion-issues-devices-wont-show-up-adb). It is also stated in the correct answer is the best solution is to change genymotion settings and point to sdk but in my case i already did it.[image]

can someone help me get rid of this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

any way in case if someone will see this post i want to point how really simple the solution by closing all the genymotion devices then running the command

**`killall adb`**. 
By killing all the adb does kill it all then i did 
**`start-server`** maybe i have another adb running some times before and i forgot about it.