# Android ADB - Daemon still not running

Tags: android, windows, adb, android-sdk-tools

**Quick Note:** I am in the Android SDK "platform-tools" directory.

My problem seems to be a bit of a weird one - Whenever I start ADB with `adb start-server`, I get the following:

- `* deamon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *`
- `* daemon started successfully *`

Well, Great. It started successfully. Now I try using `adb shell`:

- `* deamon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *` What??? I thought it already started...
- `ADB server didn't ACK`
- `* failed to start daemon *`
- `error: cannot connect to daemon`

Well, Crap. So I open Task Manager and kill adb.exe. Then I run `adb shell` (without running `adb start-server` first).
This time I get:

- `* deamon not running. starting it now on 5037 *`
- `* deamon started successfully *`
- `** deamon still not running **`
- `error: cannot connect to deamon`

So, As a brief summary - here is what I have tried:

- Rebooting my PC
- Rebooting my Phone
- Executing `adb shell`
- Executing `adb start-server` and then executing `adb shell`
- Killing ADB and Executing `adb shell`
- Killing ADB and Executing `adb start-server` and then executing `adb shell`
- Reinstalling my phone's USB Drivers
- Checking port 5037, It is not in use by any other application, and only becomes used by adb.exe when I start the daemon.

Am I missing something obvious? Help me please :P

EDIT: Solution on another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29524143/2872279

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29524143/1778421

Comment: Maybe your firewall blocks port 5037? Turn it off to check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check that you have the correct USB drivers for your Android device installed (they should either include or be downloaded with an ADB driver).
2. If you haven't installed `platform-tools`, you need to do so. You can get a copy from the Android Developer's website: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools
3. If this was already working for you and it has recently stopped, on Windows - try reinstalling the driver and/or checking that the device is actually recognised. You can do so by running `devmgmt.msc` with <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> or from command prompt.

It might be worth just checking that your USB cable is not damaged - ideally try connecting your phone to another computer or with another USB cable. This has been an issue more times than I would care to admit.

Comment: What a ridculous answer!

Comment: @Elmue I forgot about this answer 

Comment: I've since updated the answer with a more sensible solution.

Comment: Your answer does not solve the problem in the question. It is surely not a driver problem if the daemon does not start. Also a damaged USB cable will not result in the daemon not starting. The daemon even starts without any Android device beeing connected! Downgrading to another Windows version is pure nonsense. I have ADB working perfectly here on Windows 7 and 10. Your answer is useless. Probably you had a firewall problem on Windows 10.

Comment: @Elmue I forgot to remove the Windows 7 / 10 part. Of course it works on both. If you look at the question, the daemon does actually start - it seems the message is just invalid.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me using windows 10.

1. Open up task manager
2. Find adb.exe and end its process

Answer (score -2):

check port 5037 is using (another process)

or adb.exe is running (task manager), if running kill process.

Comment: I have checked Port 5037 already, It is not in use by another process. adb.exe starts and the daemon is running on port 5037 and listening but it doesnt seem to be responding to requests being sent to it. I have also killed adb.exe as you can see in the list of things I have tried.