# Unable to locate adb - android studio installed with flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I've been trying to install android studio for 3 days now and i kept running into same isue. When i tried to run AVD, i got notice "Unable to locate adb". The problem is adb.exe is already in platform-tools files. I have no idea what's wrong. I've done some research here as well and none of the answers help. Please can someone help me?? These are the messages from the log

```
7:24 PM Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 60392 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

7:24 PM Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 60392 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

7:24 PM Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037

7:24 PM Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 60728 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)
```

**Thank you**

Comment: Which OS you are working on? Is java installed on your system? Which version of Android Studio? Is the android studio installation process completed with any error or warning ?

Comment: Have you tried everything form https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036796/unable-to-locate-adb-using-android-studio?

Comment: @dev-aentgs i'm using windows 10. i have java installed. i'm using the latest one (idk what version is,  i think it's 4.0) and i don't think i run into an error during the installation.

Comment: @Nuts i guess i have but like i said before, my adb.exe is not missing and i don't have any anti virus installed on my computer other than windows defender

Comment: @dhiisti in Android Studio go to help -> check for updates, it will tell if any additional plugins or sdks need to be downloaded or updated.  
Before running AVD once go to AVD manager and check if the virtual device is created.

Comment: if everything else is ok then as @Nuts mentioned you maybe having windows defender firewall issues, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52185036/13625305) shows how to allow.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and following steps helped me out.

- Go to platform-tools folder in your Android SDK, make sure adb files aren't nested into another folder. If nested, move all files to top platform-tools folder. Platform-tool folder shouldn't be nested and it should have adb inside it
- Install SDK tools from your SDK manager (if hidden, uncheck Hide Obsolete Packages)
- Execute `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and accept the licenses
- Execute `flutter doctor -v`, it should show [✓] in Android ToolChain