# I am unable to get the HTML code from URL in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

```
package com.example.webcontentdownload;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(strings[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data = reader.read();
                while(data != -1) {
                    char  current = (char) data;
                    result += result;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Failed Malformed";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Failed IOException";
            }

        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        String result = null;


        try {
            result = task.execute("https://www.google.com/").get();
            Log.i("Contents of URL" , result);

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**This is my code, I am trying to get the html code of any URL.
I have tried the url connection method. I tried to re-install the avd also, sometimes i get 
    Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 35124 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

```
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037.
```

This is displayed in my EVENT LOG.
I would very much like your help **
[The log I am getting is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXess.png)

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888226/android-studio-adb-connection-error/35078826

Comment: For your emulator try running `adb start-server` from the command line

Comment: C:\Users\admin\AndroidStudioProjects\WebContentDownload>adb start-server
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @noureldienmohamed yes, it doesnt work, I have a problem in URL connection.