# How to update adb server version on windows 10

Tags: react-native, windows-10, adb

I want to try out react-native for a new android-app, however, I cannot build it properly because it gives me the following error:

adb server version (31) doesn't match this clien (36)

So I'm trying to update my adb version but I cannot figure out how. I installed the latest sdks and platform tools. When I use the command adb version in the AppData/Android/sdk/platform-tools/ directory it shows me the version 1.0.36 - so that seems to be ok. But if I execute adb version anywhere else on my computer it gives me 1.0.31. I added sdk/platfrom-tools/adb to my path-variable but that didn't change anything.
I didn't find a way to update it via Android Studio either.

Is there a way to update or at least locate the old adb.exe so I can delete it (or a way to use the new version in the sdk/platform-tools directory).

PS: For development I am using Huawei Y6 with the Android version 5.1.1

Comment: just follow http://stackoverflow.com/a/29524143/1778421

Comment: The commands didn't seem to help,however, found the second adb.exe in my **Program Files/Java/ADT/ directory**. Must from eclipse times I think - Android Studio used a different default directory. I didn't look through the System environment variables but only the user environment. Your answer got me there so thanks!