# ADB Server version doesn't match client

Tags: android, windows, adb

I'm trying to get started with Unity development for GearVR and in the setup process, I had to install and configure the Android SDK. In a tutorial, I was taken to a step where I had to use ADB to identify the signature of of my galaxy phone. I navigated to the platform tools directory of the android sdk and ran the command: `adb devices`, with the phone plugged in, but the command wasn't recognized.

So (in bash mode) I ran the command: `./adb devices` and got the error:

```
ADB Server version (31) doesn't match client (36); killing
* daemon started successfully *
```

When I first installed Android studio, I clicked on the installation executable multiple times which started multiple installation processes and I had to cancel some of them until I was left with just one of course. Based on other SO posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38214012/appium-adb-server-version-31-doesnt-match-this-client-36) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563561/how-to-update-adb-server-version-on-windows-10) it seems that there could be another version of adb installed somewhere else on the system, but I can't seem to figure out why/how I'm not able to use the command `adb` globally since I would have assumed that it would have been added to the PATH globally.

I've tried to use some commands in the console to find out where the other adb version might be located but I haven't been able to do so.

**What could possibly be the problem here and how might I resolve it?**

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, check Task Manager to see what adb.exe processes are running. You can right-click on one of these processes to see the location of the adb.exe file, which may show that it's running as part of an program other than the Android SDK.

In my case, I found that the Oculus Developer Hub program came with its own version of ADB, and that copying the following files from my Unity platform-tools folder (in your case, you'd want your Android SDK platform-tools folder) into the Oculus Developer Hub folder resolved the issue - you may just want to uninstall the offending software, but copying the files across should ensure that adb versions are compatible. After copying the files, I ran stopped any adb.exe processes running (using Task Manager), and then restarted Unity.

Files:

- adb.exe
- AdbWinApi.dll
- AdbWinUsbApi.dll

Unity folder: /Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/platform-tools

Oculus Developer Hub folder: C:/Program Files/Oculus Developer Hub/resources/bin

Comment: "You can right-click on one of these processes to see the location of the adb.exe file, which may show that it's running as part of an program other than the Android SDK."

This was the bit that really helped me figure out where adb was launching from! I don't even understand how that could happen running .\adb.exe but...! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your ADB is outdated. Update it by using SDK Manager.
In `Tools` folder, download the lastest `Android SDK Platform-tools` then check it back.[image]

Comment: I went through the step of installing the 6 packages after having checked the box for Android SDK Platform-tools. After the installation completed I ran the command again and it didn't work. Did you mean to say that the Android SDK Platform-tools should be uninstalled first? Maybe I'm not clear on what you meant.

Comment: If you have your broadband internet connection. You can try it. But i think update is enough. Maybe other problem which i dont know

Comment: I tried uninstalling and then reinstalling but that didn't seem to work. Does something on the device itself need to be updated?

Comment: I'm also getting this kind of error. but reversed like, adb server version (39) doesn't match this client (36); killing... I tried to downgrade the SDK version but not success. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DinithMinura I'm having the same reverse issue. Did you ever end up getting it fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when the smartphone was disconnected from Internet (wifi and mobile data). Turning wifi or mobile data on again adb devices run OK. adb devices works perfect when phone is offline few times only.

Answer (score 0):

Got this problem on Unity 2020.3.25f1 with Oculus Developer Hub on a Mac. Unity installed v4.0 while Oculus v4.1.
What solved it was to remove the `adb.exe` from `/Applications/2020.3.25f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/platform-tools` and copy/replace it with the `adb.exe` from `/Applications/Oculus Developer Hub/Contents/Resources/bin`.

After restart Unity was able to recognize the Quest 2 device in build settings.