# ADB server is not working properly

Tags: android, server, adb

My adb.exe is not working properly in android studio. When I tried to kill the server using `adb kill-server` with command prompt. even I tried to re-install android studio and sdk but still same problem. no device is detecting and saying 'Could not read Ok from ADB server'. what else to do?

[image]

Comment: You need to start adb on different port number like this `adb -P 49133 start-server`. Default port number for adb is currently in use by some other application on your PC.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29524143/1778421

Comment: 'You need to start adb on different port number like this adb -P 49133 start-server. Default port number for adb is currently in use by some other application on your PC.'                                                                                             thank you it worked.